# JQuery: Retrieving and displaying an image stored as a blob via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, blob

So I've got some JPEG images stored as blobs on a mysql database. Each row in the database has one longblob for a photo and another blob for the thumbnail image. I can retrieve the image via...

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ( $_GET['thumb'] === "true" ){
    $query = "SELECT thumb, t_mime, t_size FROM images WHERE image_id = '".$id."';";
}else{
    $query = "SELECT data, mime, size FROM images WHERE image_id = '".$id."';";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
$image = mysql_fetch_row($result);

header('Content-length: ' . $image[2]);
header('Content-type: ' . $image[1]); 
print $image[0];
?>
```

and call it via `<img src="pull.php?id=300&thumb=false"...</img>`. Now, that's all good when it's still server side. But how do I get images on the page after the user has the html? I've been working with jquery. What I've gotten so far is that the page displays a list of thumbnails, each with the #id in the alt text, then I do...

```
$("div.imgDiv").click(function(){ 
    image_id = $(this).children(".thumbnail").attr("alt");
    $.ajax({
        url :   'pull.php?id='+image_id+'&thumb=false',
        success: function(data){
            $("img#main_photo").replaceWith("<img alt='welcome' src='"+data+"' id='main_photo'");
        }
    });
});
```

The good thing is I get the data, the bad thing is it doesn't seem to want to convert that to an image; I just get a string of text. I want it to replace the main photo with the one that corresponds to the thumbnail I just clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just create an `img` element and point the `src` attribute to the script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to just point an img tag to that url for the browser to take care of. You don't want to load it into the DOM.